# My live search using livewire is not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

I am doing a live search on livewire, my search term is already binded with the livewire controller, but when I add it to the where clause in render function, it still displays all the data on the table not the one i am searching. I tried replacing the searchterm with a string as keyword in LIKE and it works. It seems that i can't use the input in searchterm as a keyword in the where clause.

here is my controller;

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;
use App\Models\Item;
use Livewire\WithPagination;

class Items extends Component
{
    use WithPagination;
    public $searchTerm;

    public function render()
    {
        $select = Item::where('itemName', 'LIKE', '%' . $this->searchTerm . '%')->paginate(6);
        return view('livewire.items', ['items' => $select]);
    }
}
```

this is my view

```html
<div class="row browse mt-6">
    <div class="col float-left category ">
        <h4 class="float-left font-weight-bold">All Categories</h4> 
        <h4 class="float-left font-weight-bold">Men</h4>  
        <h4 class="float-left font-weight-bold">Women</h4> 
    </div>
    <div class="col search-cat float-right">
        <input type="text"  id="search" placeholder="Browse Products" wire:model="searchTerm"/>
    </div>
    {{$searchTerm}}
</div>
<hr style="border-top: dotted 1px;" />

<div class="row w-100 p-1">
    <table class="table-center">
        <tbody>
        <div>
        @foreach($items as $item)
        <tr class="mx-auto">
            <div class="d-inline w-30 item-desc mx-auto m-1">
                <h4 class="pt-1">{{ $item->itemName }}</h4>
                <div class="">
                    <img src="items/{{ $item->itemPic }}.png" alt="" class="item-pic">
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col d-inline float-left">
                        Price: US ${{ $item->itemPrice }}
                    </div>
                    <div class="col d-inline float-right">
                        {{ $item->itemCOD }}</td>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            
        </tr>
        </tbody>
        @endforeach
        </div>
       
        <hr style="border-top: dotted 1px;" />  
        <div class="pagination-content">
            {{ $items->links('pagination::pagination-custom') }}
        </div>  
        <hr style="border-top: dotted 1px;" />  
       
   </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Does the `$searchTerm` variable update after you update your input field? If so, what does it display when you `dd($this->searchTerm)` in the render function _after_ initial render (so the first re-render after you update your input)? Could you also go and check your view HTML? If I look at it, I feel like I'm missing closing tags or tags are swapped (e.g. the closing `tbody` and closing `div`)

Comment: I checked the tags, but there are no problems, about the re-render, I don't know how to dd it.

Comment: Render the component first, then add `dd($this->searchTerm)` in the render function, then change your input.

Comment: I am actually using the render function in the livewire component, am I doing it wrong? i just started learning laravel. i am using the controller before, but i am having trouble fetching data when using the livewire. when i tried doing the die dump, only the dd show not the components

Comment: No you're not doing it wrong. If you make code changes after the page has loaded, because Livewire is server sided, a following request will respect your code changes. If you `dd` straight away, you'll not get your initial page load. 
However, if it doesn't make sense, you can also just put `\Log::debug($this->searchTerm)` and check the log file.

Comment: I tried the log::debug, and it shows as exactly as what i typed in the input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two things here that could potentially cause problems,

1. Your `tr` element does *not* have `wire:key`, the value to `wire:key` must be unique across the entire page
2. Your view consists of multiple root elements (if this is your entire view), these are the three root-elements in your view - and in Livewire, its very important that the view only has ***one*** root element.

   - `<div class="row browse mt-6">`
   - `<hr style="border-top: dotted 1px;" />`
   - `<div class="row w-100 p-1">`

Also, as a sidenote, your loop also closes the `tbody` tag, which is odd, so I moved that out of the loop. It also doesn't quite make sense to put `div`s and `hr`s inside the `table` tag, those should probably be outside of the `table`tag.

Here's the updated view, with `wire:key` on the `tr` and with the whole view wrapped in one `div`,

```html
<div>
    <div class="row browse mt-6">
        <div class="col float-left category ">
            <h4 class="float-left font-weight-bold">All Categories</h4> 
            <h4 class="float-left font-weight-bold">Men</h4>  
            <h4 class="float-left font-weight-bold">Women</h4> 
        </div>
        <div class="col search-cat float-right">
            <input type="text"  id="search" placeholder="Browse Products" wire:model="searchTerm"/>
        </div>
        {{$searchTerm}}
    </div>
    <hr style="border-top: dotted 1px;" />

    <div class="row w-100 p-1">
        <table class="table-center">
            <tbody>
                <div>
                    @foreach($items as $item)
                        <tr class="mx-auto" wire:key="item-{{ $item->id }}">
                            <div class="d-inline w-30 item-desc mx-auto m-1">
                                <h4 class="pt-1">{{ $item->itemName }}</h4>
                                <div class="">
                                    <img src="items/{{ $item->itemPic }}.png" alt="" class="item-pic">
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col d-inline float-left">
                                        Price: US ${{ $item->itemPrice }}
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col d-inline float-right">
                                        {{ $item->itemCOD }}</td>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </tr>
                    @endforeach
                </div>
            </tbody>
                    
            <hr style="border-top: dotted 1px;" /> 
            
            <div class="pagination-content">
                {{ $items->links('pagination::pagination-custom') }}
            </div>  

            <hr style="border-top: dotted 1px;" />  
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Have a look at this resource from the official Livewire docs,

- https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/troubleshooting#dom-diffing-issues

Comment: Hi, it now works, thanks for correcting the code. I actually modified the tags earlier, but still couldn't make it work, the wire:key really made the difference. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because you not render component

Try add <livewire:name-component /> in parent view like this

```
<div class>
 <livewire:name-component />
</div>
```

Comment: i added it to the app.blade, the render works fine, the problem is searching, it does not work